# How to create symlinks to all directories in folder(a) in folder(b)?

Tags: directory, find, symlink, creation

In some cases it might be desired to create symbolic links to all folders that are contained in one folder, e.g. `folder(a)` in another folder, e.g. `folder(b)`. Linux offers strong command line functionality, so I thought that this can easily be done with `find`:

```
find folder\(a\)/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ln -s {} \
    folder\(b\)/`echo {} | cut -d '/' -f2` \;
```

But this command doesn’t do it’s job. Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way I found out it works:

```
find folder\(a\)/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    -printf 'ln -s "../%p" folder\\(b\\)/%f\n' | sh
```

Comment: Note that `ln` “source” parameter must be **relative to `ln` “destination” directory**, *not* relative to current directory, so in this case you have to nitroduce the `../` here